# Помогите перевести функцию с JQuerry на чистый JS

Tags: javascript

Cтолкнулся с задачей, плоховато знаю JS, надо функцию обработки кнопки отмены действия в форме, перевести с JQuery на JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var states = ['', ];
var inputArea = document.querySelector("#inputarea");
var undoBtn = document.querySelector("#undo");

inputArea.addEventListener('input', function() {
 var str = inputArea.value;
 states.push(str);
});

inputarea.value = "";

undoBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (states.length === 1) {
  return false;
 } else {
  states.length = states.length - 1;
  inputArea.value = states[states.length - 1];
 }
})
```

```html
<button id="undo">
  Undo
</button>
<textarea id="inputarea">
</textarea>
```